# Proof by case analysis in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I am trying to prove a Proposition about the following function:

```
Program Fixpoint division (m:nat) (n:nat) {measure m} : nat :=
match lt_nat 0 n with
  | false => 0
  | true => match leq_nat n m with
      | false => 0
      | true => S (division (menos m n) n)
  end
end.
```

`menos` is natural subtraction.

I am trying to prove some fact involving division. I wrote down an informal proof were I first consider a case analysis in lt_nat 0 n and then in the case when lt_nat is true a further case analysis in leq_nat n m. This is in order to reduce the definition of division.

However I can not find how to express this case analysis in Coq. I tried with `destruct (leq_nat n m)` but it does nothing. I am expecting Coq to generate two subgoals: one where I need to prove my proposition assuming `leq_nat n m = false` and one assuming `leq_nat n m = true`.

Furthermore, I can not unfold the definition of division in my proof! When I try `unfold division` I get: `division_func (existT (fun _ : nat => nat) m n)`.

How can I perfom case analysis in `leq_nat n m`? Why is it that I can not unfold the definition of division as I usually do with other functions?

Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: I found that by using the tactic `case_eq ( leq_nat n m )` I can achieve the case analysis I needed. However, I still can not figure out how to apply the definition of division, i.e how to unfold it and reduce it in the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is more complicated than usual because of `Program Fixpoint`, which does not define your function as you would expect with a classic `Fixpoint`, since it needs to find a structurally recursive way of defining it. What `division` really is, is hidden in `division_func`.

Therefore, to manipulate your function, you need to prove basic lemmas, including the one stating that your function can be replaced by its body.

```
Lemma division_eq : forall m n, division m n = match lt_nat 0 n with
| false => 0
  | true => match leq_nat n m with
      | false => 0
      | true => S (division (menos m n) n)
  end
end.
```

Now, the question is how to prove this result. Here is the only solution I know, which I consider really unsatisfying.

I use the tactic `fix_sub_eq` located in `Program.Wf`, or `fix_sub_eq_ext` in `Program.Wf.WfExtensionality`.

This gives something like:

```
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold division. unfold division_func at 1.
  rewrite fix_sub_eq; repeat fold division_func.
  - simpl. destruct (lt_nat 0 n) eqn:H.
    destruct (leq_nat n m) eqn:H0. reflexivity.
    reflexivity. reflexivity.
```

But the second goal is quite complicated. The easy and general way of solving it is to use the axioms `proof_irrelevance` and `functional_extensionality`. It should be possible to prove this particular subgoal without any axioms, but I have not found the right way to do it. Instead of manually applying the axioms, you can use the second tactic `fix_sub_eq_ext` which calls them directly, leaving you a single goal.

```
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold division. unfold division_func at 1.
  rewrite fix_sub_eq_ext; repeat fold division_func.
  simpl. destruct (lt_nat 0 n) eqn:H.
  destruct (leq_nat n m) eqn:H0. reflexivity.
  reflexivity. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I have not found a better way to use `Program Fixpoint`, that's why I prefer using `Function`, which has other defaults, but generates directly the equation lemma.

```
Require Recdef.
Function division (m:nat) (n:nat) {measure (fun n => n) m} : nat :=
match lt_nat 0 n with
  | false => 0
  | true => match leq_nat n m with
      | false => 0
      | true => S (division (menos m n) n)
  end
end.
Proof.
  intros m n. revert m. induction n; intros.
  - discriminate teq.
  - destruct m. discriminate teq0.
    simpl. destruct n. destruct m; apply le_n.
    transitivity m. apply IHn. reflexivity. assumption. apply le_n.
Qed.

Check division_equation.
```

Now you have the equation lemma, you can rewrite with it and reason as usual.

About your problem with `destruct`, `destruct` does not unfold the definitions. Therefore, if you have no occurrences of the term you're destructing in your goal or any of the hypotheses, `destruct` will not do anything interesting, unless you save the equation it produces. You can use `destruct ... eqn:H` for this purpose. I did not know `case_eq` but it seems to do the same thing.