# Destruct if condition in program fixpoint coq

Tags: coq

I want to proof the  factor function correctness in [Use proof of if expression = true in then part coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012942/use-proof-of-if-expression-true-in-then-part-coq)

```
Require Import ZArith Znumtheory.

Local Open Scope Z_scope.


Require Coq.Program.Tactics.
Require Coq.Program.Wf.

Lemma divgt0 ( a b : Z ) ( agt0 : 0 < a ) ( bgt1 : 1 < b ) (dvd : (b|a) ) : 0<a/b.
Proof.
  apply Zdivide_Zdiv_lt_pos.
  auto.
  auto.
  auto.
Qed.

Program Fixpoint factor ( a b : Z ) ( agt0 : 0 < a ) ( bgt1 : 1 < b ) {measure (Z.abs_nat a)} := 
  if Zdivide_dec b a 
  then 1+factor (a/b) b (divgt0 a b agt0 bgt1 _)  bgt1 
  else 0.
Next Obligation.
  assert ( 0 < a / b < a ).
  apply Zdivide_Zdiv_lt_pos.
  auto.
  auto.
  auto.
  apply Zabs_nat_lt.
  omega.
Qed.

Lemma factor_div ( a b : Z ) ( agt0 : 0 < a ) ( bgt1 : 1 < b ) : (b ^ (factor a b agt0 bgt1) | a).
Proof.
  unfold factor.
```

after unfold I expected see a if and destruct its condition , but now I see this :

```
1 subgoal
a, b : Z
agt0 : 0 < a
bgt1 : 1 < b
______________________________________(1/1)
(b
 ^ factor_func
     (existT (fun a0 : Z => {b0 : Z & {_ : 0 < a0 & 1 < b0}}) a
        (existT (fun b0 : Z => {_ : 0 < a & 1 < b0}) b
           (existT (fun _ : 0 < a => 1 < b) agt0 bgt1))) | a)
```

How I can complete the proof?

Comment: Things are a lot more complicated if you use Program Fixpoint. Have you taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856689/proof-by-case-analysis-in-coq)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Program` gives you terms that are difficult to work with, so you should prove a lemma that `factor` is equal to its body, and then rewrite with that, instead of unfolding. (I used `match` instead of `if` to get hold of the `dvd` proof term.)

```
Lemma factor_lemma a b agt0 bgt1:
  factor a b agt0 bgt1 =
  match Zdivide_dec b a with
  | left dvd => 1+factor (a/b) b (divgt0 a b agt0 bgt1 dvd)  bgt1
  | right notdvd =>  0 end.
Proof.
  unfold factor at 1.
  unfold factor_func; rewrite Program.Wf.Fix_eq; fold factor_func.
  - reflexivity.
  - intros.
    destruct Zdivide_dec; auto.
    congruence.
Qed.
```

When you unfold and rewrite with `Fix_eq` you get such a horrible goal term to look at that it's best to fold it quickly! :-)  It can be handled with `reflexivity` or `auto` anyway.

The second goal typically requires algebraic manipulation with `omega` or similar to show that the LHS equals RHS, but in this case it was sufficient with `congruence`.

How did I know to use `Fix_eq`?  When I unfolded `factor_func` I saw it contained `Wf.Fix_sub`, so I searched for lemmas with `Search (Wf.Fix_sub).` and found a few.

Now you should continue your proof by rewriting with the lemma:

```
Lemma factor_div ( a b : Z ) ( agt0 : 0 < a ) ( bgt1 : 1 < b ) : (b ^ (factor a b agt0 bgt1) | a).
Proof.
  rewrite factor_lemma.
  destruct Zdivide_dec.

  2:   now rewrite Z.pow_0_r;apply Z.divide_1_l.
```

Now your goal state is

```
  a, b : Z
  agt0 : 0 < a
  bgt1 : 1 < b
  d : (b | a)
  ============================
  (b ^ (1 + factor (a / b) b (divgt0 a b agt0 bgt1 d) bgt1) | a)
```

which probably makes more sense.

Comment: However, in this case you should probably do some kind of induction, rather than starting to unfold `factor` immediately.

Comment: why Program Fixpoint dosen't create a lemma like factor_equation that Function make?